# How to set iron-image src to use data-binding

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have an iron-image with a placeholder, and I'd like it to show an image when I press a button. But when I update the myImages prop, the image src doesn't update. Oddly enough the placeholder prop loadingImg works, I can update it and the placeholder changes.

For example, the HTML:

```
<iron-image   preload fade 
              src$="{{myImages.test1}}"
              placeholder$="[[loadingImg]]"></iron-image>
```

and the element prop:

```
myImages: {
          type: Object,
          value: {}, 
        },
loadingImg: {
          type: String,
          value: "../../img/loading.jpg"
        }
```

and the button just sets

```
myImages."test1 = "http://example.com/img1.jpg"}
```

Initially, src should point to undefined, as myImages is empty, so myImages.test1 should be undefined. But once I give myImages.test1 a url, the img src should update. What's going wrong here?

Comment: I also noticed that if I get rid of placeholder/preload/fade, and just assign src= [[loadingImg]] it will work. Does it have to do with using an object containing strings vs just using a string?

Answer (score 0):

Changes to object properties aren't observable by default. In order to make this work, you need to use this.notifyPath()

This is why the prop loadingImg, which is just a string was causing the page to update on change, but the subproperty myImages.test1 was not.

Fixed sample code:

```
updateImage: function(imgSrc) {
this.myImages.test1 = imgSrc;
this.notifyPath('myImages.test1');
}
```